# `<ac:image>`などコロンを含むタグを、Pythonのlxmlライブラリで生成したいです。

Tags: python, html

## 環境

- Python3.9
- [lxml](https://lxml.de/) v4.9.2

## やりたいこと

HTMLファイルをConfluenceにインポートするために、[Confluence用のXML](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf713/confluence-storage-format-1077913458.html)に変換したいです。

Confluenceでは、画像は`<ac:image>`タグを使って表現します。
Pythonの[lxml](https://lxml.de/)ライブラリを使って、`<ac:image>`タグを生成したいです。

## 問題

以下のコードを実行すると、ValueErrorが発生しました。

```
from lxml import etree
elm = etree.Element("ac:image")
print(elm.tag)
```

```
File src/lxml/etree.pyx:3042, in lxml.etree.Element()
File src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi:101, in lxml.etree._makeElement()
File src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi:1754, in lxml.etree._tagValidOrRaise()
ValueError: Invalid tag name 'ac:image'
```

## 質問

コロンを含むタグをlxmlで生成したい場合は、どのように実行すればよいでしょうか？

`lxml.html.fromstring`で適当な名前で要素を作り、後からtagを書き替えることで、やりたいことは実現できました。

```
from lxml import html
# テキトーな名前でタグを生成する
elm = html.fromstring("<foo />")
print(elm.tag)
# → image
elm.tag = "ac:image"
print(elm.tag)
# → ac:image
```

ただ、正しいやり方ではない気がするので、もっと良い方法を知りたいです。

Comment: コロンの前にある文字列はnamespaceというものらしいですね。[XML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp), [XML Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) こんな記事が参考になるかも。[ElementTreeやlxmlで名前空間を含むXMLの要素を取得する](https://orangain.hatenablog.com/entry/namespaces-in-xpath), [...lxml、デフォルト名前空間...](https://jhalfmoon.com/dbc/2019/10/20/%E3%83%88%E3%83%9B%E3%83%9B%E3%81%AA%E7%96%91%E5%95%8F13-python%E3%80%81lxml%E3%80%81%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E7%A9%BA%E9%96%93%E3%81%A8xpath/), [namespace付きのXML...](https://qiita.com/dmikita/items/4e8226081f2861a66dbd)

Comment: ちなみに質問は1つの要素だけを単独で扱いたいように書かれていますが、上記コメントのnamespace関連情報と、こちらのページ [XML schema for the Confluence storage format](http://www.amnet.net.au/~ghannington/confluence/readme.html) でユーザーが独自に作成した説明およびここからダウンロードできるスキーマパッケージを見較べてみて、全ての情報が記述された全体として有効なXMLファイルを読み込んだり作成したりして、その中で一部の要素を操作する形で実現するのではないかと思われます。それから質問に書かれた参照ページには[Confluence Source Editor](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210722/confluence-source-editor?tab=overview&hosting=server)というのがあるようですが、これを使うのでは駄目なのでしょうか？

Comment: 検索してみた結果では、この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Registering namespaces with lxml before parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59850806/9014308), [How to insert an attribute with the right namespace prefix using lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58833073/9014308), [How to convert an xml element object into a string with a namespace prefix in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43893038/9014308), [lxml: how to know what namespace to use for namespace prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59539236/9014308)